# Linear regression, input centered and mean of the output

Tags: regression, linear, posterior

[image]

Why "If the inputs are centered, the mean of the
output is equally likely to be positive or negative"?

Comment: This conclusion is not generally true for linear regression, but it *is* true because of the Normality assumption: this implies the "output" will be Normally distributed; and the mean and median coincide in any Normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i use the median?

Comment: The median (of a continuous distribution) is *defined* in terms of the "equally likely..." phrase in your quotation.  Therein is the crux of this matter: it is a bit of a mystery how an analysis *that has nothing to do with medians* could yield such a definite result about a median.  This is why the Normality assumption is crucial: without it, that conclusion would not generally be true.

Comment: I mean: how are related the mean/median of the output and the fact that the inputs are centered?

Comment: You say that for every Gaussian the median is equally likely to be positive or negative? If it is so, i think i've understood

Comment: No: the median is a property of a Gaussian.  It's just a number, not a random variable.  But a Gaussian random variable is equally likely to exceed or to lie below its median: that defines the median of any continuous random variable.